# Google maps is not showing

Tags: google-maps

```
function initMap() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 10,
                center: {lat: -33.9, lng: 151.2}
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
            document.getElementById('map-id').style.position = 'absolute' / 'fixed' / 'potato' / 'whatever';
        });
            setMarkers(map);
        }
        var beaches = [
            ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
            ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
            ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
            ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
            ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
        ];

        function setMarkers(map) {
            var image = {
                url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
                size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
            };
            var shape = {
                coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
                type: 'poly'
            };
            for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
                var beach = beaches[i];
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {lat: beach[1], lng: beach[2]},
                    map: map,
                    icon: image,
                    shape: shape,
                    title: beach[0],
                    zIndex: beach[3]
                });
            }
        }
```

m trying to show google map but when i inspect element in the browser then it show me position: relative; overflow: hidden;

Thanks!

Comment: Update your question and add  the html code  .. (and css for map id to)

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that you have the following:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map')
```

and

```
 document.getElementById('map-id').style.position = 'absolute' / 'fixed' / 'potato' / 'whatever';
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you are referencing the div that holds the map in both of these statements. I made a JSFiddle where the div holding the map has an ID of 'map-id' and I changed the first line of code in my answer to the following:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-id')
```

I also took out the second line of code I posted in my answer, because it didn't seem relevant.

I made sure there was CSS to set the height to 100% for that div and it looks like everything works. Please see my fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/790ryvnf/

Please note that you will need to put your own API key in this code for it to work, I took mine out for security.

I hope this helps!